# Xupload yii extension maxNumberOfFiles

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii-xupload

Hello guys I am trying to tweak the xupload ext's functionality what I am trying to do is to render the user all of their uploaded images so even if they refresh the page after they upload an image it will still be rendered on the #modal-gallery table..I know how to use CActiveRecord
The question is:

how will I let my form know that the user already have an uploaded image?

my form's code is:

```
 <?php
    $this->widget('xupload.XUpload', array(
        'url' => Yii::app( )->createUrl("/UserAccountImages/upload",array('id'=>$model->id)),
        'model' => $imageForm,
        'htmlOptions' => array('id'=>'user-account-images-form'),
        'attribute' => 'file',
        'multiple' => true,
        'options' => array(
            'maxNumberOfFiles'=>8,
            'maxFileSize' => 3000000,
            'acceptFileTypes' => "js:/(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$/i",
        ),
        'formView' => 'application.views.UserAccountImages._form',
    )    
    );
    ?>
```

Comment: Why do you want your widgit to know if the user has already uploaded an image? is it to limit their amount of uploads or for some other reason?

Comment: @jelle yes and also to display those image on the table

Comment: do you have any answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks to me like the extension doesn't save anything in your database. so you will need some sort of way to count the amount of files a user uploaded, you can do this by looking through the files you saved on the server but you need to know what file was uploaded by which user. or you can save an entry in your database for each file a user uploads. with a relation to the user and data about the uploaded file. (You'll need to delete this record when a file is deleted.)

If you're able to get a count of the files per user you should be able to set the  `'maxNumberOfFiles'=>8 - getFilecountOfCurrentUser() //<-The method you'll need to implement`

Then to show the files in the table...

You can go 2 ways:

1. change the extensions view so it shows files already uploaded by a user, (the file located in the extensions /view directory called: "form.php".
2. Add the files to the table when the page loads with java script.

For both ways to work, you'll need to know which file belongs to which user.

Comment: Or you can always try to find an extension which covers your needs better.